# ¿Cómo escalar una variable?

Tags: r

Tengo un vector numérico, por ejemplo, algo así:

```
set.seed(2022)
x <- runif(100)
x

[1] 0.815977655 0.647259330 0.120328584 0.543800154 0.184729989 0.635790846 0.074298996
  [8] 0.041975932 0.370317112 0.757252903 0.001862073 0.159799489 0.144741664 0.519396774
 [15] 0.609476454 0.122510589 0.773217809 0.514508979 0.595448172 0.850909892 0.842836875
 [22] 0.570326562 0.426557253 0.137205496 0.163092609 0.935081260 0.537011651 0.997654765
 [29] 0.478951844 0.773609737 0.467988231 0.637632510 0.256522512 0.405364905 0.170882536
 [36] 0.067975666 0.846031823 0.549878274 0.804842540 0.765064378 0.642243026 0.441700250
 [43] 0.649381436 0.524535179 0.867232889 0.100646125 0.887149954 0.627954275 0.363797884
 [50] 0.852652489 0.195017625 0.285152013 0.742162668 0.369118812 0.628566523 0.576754153
 [57] 0.302247770 0.426244156 0.405559716 0.141474303 0.546878559 0.537077268 0.797159597
 [64] 0.820139240 0.059507780 0.832793485 0.412733460 0.458632631 0.206908659 0.593788662
 [71] 0.859187800 0.867046658 0.859854081 0.780411754 0.556510594 0.068849680 0.562369511
 [78] 0.743696145 0.433008340 0.480763005 0.393950337 0.404539135 0.790388042 0.739234230
 [85] 0.130354437 0.398125553 0.076245487 0.231681422 0.524064215 0.808389115 0.213894012
 [92] 0.161496287 0.633175631 0.460216064 0.397636808 0.278544191 0.095972190 0.990140246
 [99] 0.643628040 0.745793494
```

Me gustaría "escalar" estos valores para obtener un porcentaje que vaya de 0 a 100, aunque en particular, no quiero que se llegue exactamente al 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para llevar un vector de numéricos a una escala de 0 a 1, la formula clásica es:

```
(x-min(x))/((max(x))-min(x))
```

Multiplicándolo por 100 lo llevamos a una escala de 0 a 100, pero si además no queremos que el valor máximo sea 100, simplemente hay que hacer que el máximo sea el valor máximo del vector más un pequeño residuo:

```
(x-min(x))/((max(x)+1e-08)-min(x))*100
```

Ejemplo:

```
set.seed(2022)
x <- runif(100)

(x-min(x))/((max(x)+1e-08)-min(x))*100
    
  [1]  81.755528  64.812411  11.896704  54.422781  18.364055  63.660717   7.274297
  [8]   4.028334  37.001179  75.858241   0.000000  15.860471  14.348327  51.972132
 [15]  61.018160  12.115826  77.461477  51.481288  59.609404  85.263511  84.452798
 [22]  57.086629  42.648955  13.591526  16.191175  93.716211  53.741063  99.999999
 [29]  47.910551  77.500836  46.809558  63.845661  25.573640  40.520766  16.973459
 [36]   6.639293  84.773643  55.033161  80.637312  76.642689  64.308661  44.169653
 [43]  65.025518  52.488144  86.902707   9.920142  88.902829  62.873749  36.346502
 [50]  85.438507  19.397165  28.448686  74.342842  36.880843  62.935232  57.732104
 [57]  30.165485  42.617513  40.540330  14.020210  54.731922  53.747652  79.865772
 [64]  82.173445   5.788927  83.444216  41.260735  45.870045  20.591292  59.442752
 [71]  86.094799  86.884005  86.161709  78.183911  55.699195   6.727063  56.287562
 [78]  74.496838  43.296789  48.092432  39.374487  40.437840  79.185755  74.048761
 [85]  12.903525  39.793772   7.469769  23.079035  52.440848  80.993468  21.292779
 [92]  16.030868  63.398090  46.029057  39.744691  27.785112   9.450774  99.245372
 [99]  64.447748  74.707459
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objeto de no llevarlo a 100? Existe un causa técnica? O solo lo realiza como un ejemplo académico?

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo, esto es la reformulación de la pregunta de otro usuario, dónde quería escalar la variable pero que el valor máximo nunca llegara a 100, no había otra razón más que eso.